# No value specified for parameter 1

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting the error saying "No Specific Value for Parameter 1". I want to display the bookings of the logged in user from the UserId

```
    public ArrayList<booking> viewRestaurantsBooking() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("In viewRestaurantsBooking!");
    ArrayList<booking> myRestaurantsBookingList = new ArrayList<booking>();
    try {
        String selectStatement = "select * from famnection.bookrest where UserId=?";
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectStatement);
        ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();


        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Record Found!");
            booking myBookings = new booking();
            System.out.println("Restaurant Name=" + rs.getString("restName"));
            myBookings.setRestName(rs.getString("restName"));
            System.out.println("Booking Date=" + rs.getString("bookingdate"));
            myBookings.setBookingdate(rs.getDate("bookingdate"));
            System.out.println("Booking Time=" + rs.getString("bookingtime"));
            myBookings.setTime(rs.getString("bookingtime"));
            myRestaurantsBookingList.add(myBookings);

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception("Error:" + ex.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("myRestaurantsList SIZE=" + myRestaurantsBookingList.size());
    return myRestaurantsBookingList;
}
```

Comment: What UserID do you think it is looking for in the where clause when you execute your query?

Comment: Error messages are [excellent search keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=No+value+specified+for+parameter+1). Don't disrespect and typo them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill parameter in PreparedStatement

```
preparedStatement.setLong(1, someIdentifier)
```